# How to define error bar in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to define error bars on both ends for matlab. Usually, the example of matlab would be http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/ref/errorbar.html where the error bar would take the standard deviation (E) and make it equal(symmetric) on both ends.

I would like to define two points specifically apart from plotting the exact point (x,y).

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to plot asymmetric error bars (i.e. different lengths above and below the line), or how to plot error bars *without* plotting the line?

Comment: Do you want to use L and U parameters for specify low and upper error distance?

Answer (score 7):

As Singlet mentions, the L and U parameters for errorbar should do the job:

```
% Create some example input data.
x = 1:10
y = cumsum( randn(1,10) );
lower = y - ( rand(1,10) );
upper = y + ( rand(1,10) );

% Convert absolute lower and upper bounds into the relative values 
% values that are expected by the errorbar function.
L = y - lower;
U = upper - y;

figure(1);
clf;
hold('on');
plot( x, y, 'b-' );
errorbar( x, y, L, U, 'r', 'Marker', 'none', 'LineStyle', 'none' );
```